# How to reduce the repeat object.chain in react-native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, mobx, mobx-react

I have react-native code with mobx like below, as you guys see, I need reference `this.props.store.user.avatar` to get deep object value from props, I don't wanna use the long syntax repeatedly, I know I can let it be a instance variable in constructor for example2, but I find that's a anti-pattern by the [posts](http://reactjs.cn/react/tips/props-in-getInitialState-as-anti-pattern.html), it actually occurs some side-effect by my experiment cause the constructor execute only once when components initial, so I use the third way for example3, as you like, I create function in components and return the value by the long syntax, that's what can I do in my best, but I don't like this way, it looks not elegant, so anyone has better suggest or solution/way?

## Example1 : My question

```
@observer
export default class Profile extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

 render() {
    return(
        <BasicInfo 
          avatar = { this.props.store.user.avatar }
          displayName = { this.props.store.user.displayName  } 
          location = { this.props.store.user.location }
        />
        )
  }
}
```

## Example2 : Anti-Pattern

```
@observer
export default class Profile extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.avatar = this.props.store.user.avatar
    this.displayName = this.props.store.user.displayName
    this.location = this.props.store.user.location
  }

 render() {
    return(
        <BasicInfo 
          avatar = { this.avatar }
          displayName = { this.displayName  } 
          location = { this.location }
        />
        )
  }
}
```

## Example3 : Anti-Pattern

```
@observer
export default class Profile extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      avatar: this.props.store.user.avatar,
      displayName: his.props.store.user.displayName,
      location: this.props.store.user.location,
    }
  }

 render() {
    return(
        <BasicInfo 
          avatar = { this.state.avatar }
          displayName = { this.state.displayName  } 
          location = { this.state.location }
        />
        )
  }
}
```

## Example 4 : It work, but exist better way?

```
@observer
export default class Profile extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  avatar(){ return this.props.store.user.avatar}
  displayName(){ return this.props.store.user.displayName}
  location(){ return this.props.store.user.location}

 render() {
    return(
        <BasicInfo 
          avatar = { this.avatar() }
          displayName = { this.displayName()  } 
          location = { this.location() }
        />
        )
  }
}
```

## Example 5 : This is a good way, but it not work on callback

```
@observer
export default class Profile extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

callback = () => {
  Actions.aboutMeEdit({ avatar: user.avatar })
  // there are not work
}


render() {
  const { user } = this.props.store;
  return(
    <BasicInfo 
      avatar = { user.avatar }
      displayName = { user.displayName  } 
      location = { user.location }
      callback = { this.callback }
    />
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe `render() { const u = this.props.store.user; return ( /* prop = u.avatar */ ); }`?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this to reduce the repetition:

```
render() {
const { user } = this.props.store;
return(
  <ScrollView>
    <BasicInfo 
      avatar = { user.avatar }
      displayName = { user.displayName  } 
      location = { user.location }
    />
    )
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is a way, but it only work in render(), It not work if my code like below `callback = () => {
  Actions.aboutMeEdit({ avatar: user.avatar })
  // there are not work
}


render() {
const { user } = this.props.store;
return(
  <ScrollView>
    <BasicInfo 
      avatar = { user.avatar }
      displayName = { user.displayName  } 
      location = { user.location }
      callback = { this.callback }
    />
    )
}`

Comment: Please edit with proper code format. Can't read that sorry @Tsao

Comment: Timothy Karvonen, write in the example5

Comment: @Tsao thanks. No in that case like that it would not work. What you could do in that case is to pass user as a parameter in render to callback. But i get that is not what you are looking for. You are looking for a way of shortening the object call 'globally' within the class and to my knowledge that is not possible without breaking "anti pattern 2". I would like to know if you find any way of doing this without letting the component hold the state.

Answer (score 0):

Use **spread**:

```
render() {
  const { user } = this.props.store;

  return (
    <ScrollView>
      <BasicInfo {...user} callback={this.callback.bind(this)} />
    </ScrollView>
  )
}
```